# Identity Matrix generator fill the matrix with wrongs values

Tags: c, matrix

I have written a simple function in `C` that should return an identity matrix of the desired size

```
float **ident(int n) { 
    float **b= allocate_mtx(n,n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
            if(i=j) {
                b[i][j]=1;
            }
            else {
                b[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
  //print generated matrix to check if is correct
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
            printf("%.3f    ",b[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return b;
}
```

The expected result should be

```
1.000   0.000   0.000 
0.000   1.000   0.000 
0.000   0.000   1.000
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and the print section of the method prints this

```
0.000   0.000   208.000 
0.000   1.000   130.000 
0.000   0.000   1.000
```

Why this strange behaviour? Any suggestion to fix the issue?

Comment: `i=j` should be `i==j`

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth the code compiles correctly, and I get no errors.Simply the output is wrong and I don't understand the reason. The method is pretty simple, so people that know language better than me should easily find the cause of the issue.

Comment: So you should debug it.  This is your 4th or 5th question in succession where you haven't bothered to do any debugging, but just dumped your code to SO.  Please stop it.

Comment: @AndreaF: If an answer is helpful for you, please vote it up. You can do it to many answers. If an answer solves your problem, accept it. You can accept only one of the answers.

Comment: This was written directly in C and only a distraction error caused the issue. Nobody is obbligated to help me, please stop do uncostructive comments.

Comment: I saw that I was slightly wrong again (-(-1)). My best wishes for you journey to C. If you have the option: try C++ instead of C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Banthar wrote in his comment, `i=j` should be `i==j`.

The rest of your code looks fine to me, except that `int i, j;` is missing from the *indent* function body.

To spot this bug next time, and to spot other bugs without having to ask for help, enable warnings in your compiler. For example, `gcc -W -Wall` displays the following warning for me:

```
t.c:7: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

`clang -W -Wall` also displays a warning:

```
t.c:7:21: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
```

This immediately points to the bug in the code.

If you get 0 compiler errors, 0 compiler warnings on your code, but it still produces strange result, you may want to run the compiled program using `valgrind`, which will pinpoint some memory access bugs for you. If you don't get any messages from valgrind, run your program in a debugger step-by-step (or using breakpoints) or add some `printf`s and see at which point it starts failing.

Comment: Ops I haven't noticed this. THANkS!

Answer (score 3):

Be careful of the  `if(i=j)`. That is not by any means equal to `if(i==j)`.

Comment: Ops I haven't noticed this. THANkS!